# PDO isn't working on PHP and MySql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have an amazon ec2 instance (amazon linux) setup with LAMP installed. I am trying out following example, which seems not to be working, it outputs "test" in browser and no error or no other output. I have a doubt that PDO isn't enabled for PHP , how do I find that out ? I have enabled mysql and mysql_pdo extensions in php.ini

```
function getDB()
{
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "abc";
    $dbpass = "abc123";
    $dbname = "test";

    $mysql_conn_string = "mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname";

    try{
        $dbConnection = new PDO($mysql_conn_string, $dbuser, $dbpass); 
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex) {

        echo($ex->getMessage());
    }

    return $dbConnection;
}

echo("test");
$db = getDB();

try {
    //connect as appropriate as above
    $db->query('hi'); //invalid query!
} catch(PDOException $ex) {
    echo "An Error occured!"; //user friendly message
    echo($ex->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: You can add `error_reporting( E_ALL ); ini_set( 'display_errors', 'On' );` at the beginning of your script, and test for PDO with `class_exists("PDO");`, for instance. Oh, and `phpinfo();` of course, to see what modules are actually enabled.

Comment: @kenney thanks that helped

Answer (score 1):

Create a test file caled test.php and only write

`<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

and open this page up in your browser and look for a line containing **PDO**.

Assuming that you have found **PDO** line please check for **PDO drivers** to see if mysql is a supported driver. or you can simply place the code below in the same file and check it

`<?php print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers()); ?>`

Other solutions to check **PDO** availability can be

```
<?php
if (!defined('PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME')) {
echo 'PDO unavailable';
}
?>
```

**or**

```
<?php
    var_dump(extension_loaded('PDO' )); //should return a boolean value
    var_dump(extension_loaded('pdo_mysql')); //should return a boolean value
    var_dump(get_loaded_extensions());
?>
```

**or using command line**

`$ php -m`

Comment: Not exactly what i need, but it helped to check if PDO is loaded or not